# Build multiple branches in parallel on Jenkins slave/master configuration from a single job

Tags: git, testing, github, jenkins

I have a git repo setup that has many people pushing to it. I have a job in Jenkins that polls this repo for updates to all branches. I have the Jenkins job setup with a remote machine, and is distributing builds to it from the job, however it is always building the same branch locally AND remotely.

Can I set up the job so that when it polls it takes the first in line build, and then queues up the next job to be distributed to the next available executor? I do not need the same branch to build multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do this with a parameterized job taking the name of the branch to build

http://julianhigman.com/blog/2012/02/22/building-github-branches-with-jenkins/

The question now will be how to automate passing the branch into the job.

Also, as you have it all the branch build history will be in one place

I would go with having a dedicated job per branch so as to keep track of the builds specific for each branch. You can generate these jobs from a template job using [Job DSL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) then each branch will rebuild as and when it changes

Comment: For my needs it's fine to have the build info in one location. It just seems extremely odd that when a job polls the SCM and finds multiple branches that need to be built, it takes the top priority branch and starts it on both executors... I had "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" checked, and restricted where the job could run. I removed the "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" option, but now it only builds one branch at a time, which is not what I'd like.